# Spring Transaction Management usage

Tags: spring

Can anybody provide me an example for Spring Transaction management? I have queries like how it basically works? In Java EE , Application server container used to take care of the transaction using EJB's. I wanted to know ,how spring frameworks helps in the same way?

Comment: did you go through the official documentation from spring: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: summarized in  http://javaidm.blogspot.in/2016/02/how-transaction-is-managed-in-spring.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope [Introduction to Spring Framework transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) will help.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Framework’s transaction management support doesn't requires an application server.

Spring Frameworks Claims  declarative transactions of spring framework offer more powerful  and more productive programming model than EJB CMT.

Compared to transaction management using EJB Spring frameworks enables application developers to use a consistent programming model in any environment. Once we write our code once it can benefit from different transaction management strategies in different environments.

The Spring Framework provides both declarative and programmatic transaction management.

programmatic transaction management - developers work with the Spring Framework transaction abstraction, which can run over any underlying transaction infrastructure. 
declarative model - developers typically write little or no code related to transaction management, and hence do not depend on the Spring Framework transaction API, or any other transaction API.

Answer (score 0):

- Spring framework provides central interface for transaction
  management i.e. 'PlatformTransactionManager'
- There are many implementations if it, one which you can quickly
  relate to is DataSourceTransactionManager.
- Now, this transaction manager does the lower level work of beginning,
  rollback and commit of transaction for you.
- If you see the source of DataSourceTransactionManager you will see
  the same kind of transaction management code that you have seen when
  you handle transaction using JDBC api
- But importantly, all these things happen declaratively as part of
  proxy advise using Spring AOP

Begin Transaction

```
DataSource ds = /*initialize DS here*/
Connection con = ds.getConnection();
con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Commit Transaction

```
com.commit();
```